# c++ void function not changing value of string

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to solve Q1.3 on CTCI: Write a method to replace all spaces in a string with '%20'. You may assume that the string has sufficient space at the end to hold the additional characters, and that you are given the "true" length of the string.

I ran my function on main and it works, but when I pass the function through main, I keep getting the original string "Mr. John Smith" instead of "Mr%20John%20Smith". Here's my code.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string test = "Mr John Smith          ";
    int length = 13;
    URLify(test, length);
    cout << test << endl;
    return 0;
}

void URLify(string a, int length){
    string b = a;
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        if(b[0] != ' '){
            a[counter]= b[0];
            counter++;
        }
        else{
            a[counter] = '%';
            a[counter+1] = '2';
            a[counter+2] = '0';
            counter = counter + 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass a **reference** to the string, so you can change the original:  `void URLify(string& a, int length)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing `a` *by value*, so a copy of it is created and *that* is being modified. Pass it *by reference* instead: `string& a`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass by reference not by value. Should be:

```
void URLify(std::string& a, int length)
```