# Swap two strings from parameter list C++

Tags: c++, string, swap

I'm attempting to swap two strings in C++ with the method below. I pass them in as parameters, and within the method itself they seem to be swapping properly. However, when I output the strings after calling the swap method they haven't changed. Any idea why? Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
void swap(char* stringA, char* stringB){
    char temp[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
        temp[i] = stringA[i];
    }
    
    stringA = stringB;
    stringB = temp;
}
```

---

```
int main() {
    char *greeting = "Hello";
    char *dismissal = "Good Bye";

    swap(greeting, dismissal);
    printf("greeting: %s dismissal: %s\n", greeting, dismissal);
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output:

```
greeting: Hello dismissal: Good Bye
```

Comment: In C++, a simple `std::swap(string1, string2);` where `string1` and `string2` are `std::string` is all that's required.  What's the reason for using `char *` (which are not strings, but pointers)?  Also, this looks like `C` and not `C++`.  Are you sure you chose the right language tags?

Comment: **In C++ use `std::string`.** Save yourself the unending nightmare of misery, pain and suffering that is C strings.

Comment: Your code also has undefined behaviour, since it copies 100 characters from the array `greeting` (from `main()`) which points to the first element of an array of only six characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ void function not changing value of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164039/c-void-function-not-changing-value-of-string)

Answer (score 1):

You are only modifying copies of the pointers in your `swap` function. If you want to change the pointers at the call site, you need to pass them by reference. Also, you are treating the contents of the strings as containing 100 elements, but they don't, so you are invoking undefined behavior when you index at those positions.

You can simply write the function like this:

```
void swap(char const * &stringA, char const* &stringB) {
    auto temp = stringA;    
    stringA = stringB;
    stringB = temp;
}
```

or just use `std::swap` directly.

Also, from c++11, you can't assign a string literal to a `char *`, you need to assign it to a `char const *`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/znahax).